# Is a flat space a affine space?

Tags: differential-geometry, affine-geometry

An affine space of dimension *n* on $\mathbb R$ is defined to be a non-empty set $E$ such that there exists a vector space $V$ of dimension *n* on $\mathbb R$ and a mapping

$\phi:E \times E \rightarrow V,\space\space\space
     (A,B) \mapsto \phi(A,B):=\vec {AB}$

that obeys the following properties:

(i) For any point $O \in E$, the function

$\phi_O: E \rightarrow V,\space\space\space
      M \mapsto \vec {OM}$

is bijective.

(ii) For any triplet $(A,B,C)$ of elements of $E$, the following relation holds:

$\vec {AB} + \vec {BC} = \vec {AC}.$

My question is do all flat manifold can be considered an affine space?

Comment: By any meaningful sense, I would say no.

Comment: @ Gae. S. Can you give me a counter example?

Comment: An affine space is an axiomatic machinery that has the purpose of inducing a structure that is, topologically, $\Bbb R^n$ except that you only care about the action of linear maps and translations. So every flat mainfold that isn't topologically $\Bbb R^n$ can't be reasonably considered an affine space.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a right circular cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: what axiom does it violates?

Comment: The first. You have no topology in the definition, but certainly it is obvious that there is no continuous bijection. Of course, there is always a bijection between two sets of the same cardinality, so without continuity you will have to work harder.